# Return the number of new Cells added to a board

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D Arraylist with dimensions **2 rows** and **2 cols**:
    |  0|  1|
    +---+---+
  0 |  0|  0|
    +---+---+
  1 |  0|  0|
    +---+---+
and method `expandBoard(int row, int col)` which expands the board with the given coordinates. For example:

```
expandBoard(4, 3){
    |  0|  1|  2|  3|
    +---+---+---+---+
  0 |  0|  0|  0|  0|
    +---+---+---+---+
  1 |  0|  0|  0|  0|
    +---+---+---+---+
  2 |  0|  0|  0|  0|
    +---+---+---+---+
  3 |  0|  0|  0|  0|
    +---+---+---+---+
  4 |  0|  0|  0|  0|
    +---+---+---+---+
}
```

Now, three rows have been added to the board and as well as two cols (`addedRows = 3, addedCols = 2`). How can I determine the total number of new cells that have been created as a result of expansion?

```
public int expand(int row, int col){
        int rowsCount = 0;
        int colsCount = 0;
        int addedRows = 0;
        int addedCols = 0;
        int cols = getPhysicalCols();

        if ((minRow <= row && maxRow >= row)
                && (minCol <= col && maxCol >= col)) {
            return 0;
        } 

        else {
            if (row < minRow) {
                while (row != minRow) {
                    addRowTop();
                    rowsCount++;
                    addedRows++ ;
                }

                if (col < minCol) {
                    while (col != minCol) {
                        addColLeft();
                        colsCount++;
                        addedCols++;
                    }
                }
                if (col > maxCol) {
                    while (maxCol != col) {
                        addColRight();
                        colsCount++;
                        addedCols++;
                    }
                }
            }
return (addedRows * cols) + getPhysicalRows() + getPhysicalCols();
}

public void addRowTop(){
        ArrayList<T> rowLine = new ArrayList<T>();
        myBoard.add(0, rowLine);
        this.minRow -= 1;
        origCol = maxCol - minCol;
        for(int col = 0; col <= origCol; col++){
            rowLine.add(col, this.element);
        }
    }

public int getPhysicalRows(){
        return myBoard.size();
    }
public int getPhysicalCols(){
        return myBoard.get(myBoard.size() - 1).size();

    }
```

Comment: Pertinent code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're existing matrix is *M* rows by *N* columns, and you want to add *x* rows and *y* columns, then the number of cells to be created is equal to:

```
(M + x) * (N + y) - (M * N)
```

That is, the dimensions of the resultant matrix `(M + x) * (N + y)` minus the dimensions of the original matrix `(M * N)`.

Comment: I assume both M and N are from the original 2d Arraylist, i.e. before expansion? @LukeMWillis

Comment: Thank you! I'm curious how easy was that to figure out the formula for you?

Comment: @John Glad to help! Having done quite a bit of this sort of thing, I was able to solve it fairly quickly, but that all comes with experience. You'll get there with time. :) (Also, if I answered your question, please accept this as the answer)

Comment: Sure thing! Thank you again!